# Getting a conditional maximum in data.table using .SD

Tags: r, data.table, conditional-statements, aggregate

I've been trying to to do this for a while now but it has proven pretty difficult so I had to ask for your valuable help.

My problem is that I have a vector with three main camps: **ID**, **date** and **state**. The **ID** takes repeats several times in the DB because of several registers. The **date** is just the date the register was done. And the **state** could be 'active' or 'inactive'.

I need to do the following: for each document I must take only the most recent one with the following priority: if there is an 'Active' register I must take the most recent of all possible 'Active' ones, and if there is not active I must take the most recent one in general.

For example let's say I have this

`data.table(ID=rep(seq(1,3),each=3),state=c("active","active","active","inactive","inactive","inactive","active","active","inactive"),Date=as.Date(c("2016-01-01","2016-01-03","2016-01-02","2016-01-04","2016-01-05","2016-01-06","2016-01-07","2016-01-08","2016-01-10")),value=seq(1,9))`

`ID     state     Date     value
1:  1   active 2016-01-01    1
2:  1   active 2016-01-03    2
3:  1   active 2016-01-02    3
4:  2 inactive 2016-01-04    4
5:  2 inactive 2016-01-05    5
6:  2 inactive 2016-01-06    6
7:  3   active 2016-01-07    7
8:  3   active 2016-01-08    8
9:  3 inactive 2016-01-10    9`

I've been trying to do an operation similar to:

`dx[,list(if (length(.SD[state=="active"])==0)
                     {.SD[which.max(Date)]}
          else {.SD[state=="active"]
                   [which.max(Date)]})
    ,by='ID']`

So that I get something like:

`ID   state      Date     value
1:  1   active  2016-01-03     2
2:  2 inactive  2016-01-06     6
3:  3   active  2016-01-08     8`

I want to do a vectorized operation with data.table. If you please can help me it will be awesome!.

Thank you,
Aldo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a modification of the OP's code to get the expected output.  Grouped by 'ID', `if` there are `any` 'active' strings in the 'state', we get the index of the maximum 'Date' where the 'state' is 'active' (using `which.max`) and Subset the Data.table (`.SD[which.max...`) or `else` we get the maximum 'Date' index (`which.max(Date)`) and then use `.SD`.

```
 dx[,if(any(state=='active')) .SD[which.max(Date[state=='active'])] 
            else .SD[which.max(Date)], ID]
 #    ID    state       Date value
 #1:  1   active 2016-01-03     2
 #2:  2 inactive 2016-01-06     6
 #3:  3   active 2016-01-08     8
```

---

Or another option would be to `order` the 'Date' and 'state' column and select the first observation by 'ID'

```
dx[order(ID,state, -Date),.SD[1L], ID]
#   ID    state       Date value
#1:  1   active 2016-01-03     2
#2:  2 inactive 2016-01-06     6
#3:  3   active 2016-01-08     8
```